# Sending a function fron <input> onChange function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

My component:

```
class Admin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  uploadFile = async (event, refetch) => {
    await uploadFileToBucket(event, true);
    refetch(); // refetch is undefined
  };

  render() {
    return (
     <GraphQlDataFetcher query={getObjectsInDefaultBucket()}>
        {(data, refetch) => (
           <Files files={data.bucketObjects}/>
            <input type="file" onChange={(refetch) => this.uploadFile(event, refetch)}/>

          )}
       </GraphQlDataFetcher>

    );
  }
}


export default Admin
```

When the file upload is complete, I want to refetch the graphql-query. So I need to send the refetch function up to my `uploadFile`. How do I do that?

Comment: Input onChange gives you only event but not refetch. To get the latest data do fetch call like you are doing uploadFileToBucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that doing this:

```
<input type="file" onChange={ (refetch) => this.uploadFile(event, refetch) } />
```

you are overriding the `refetch` method passed by `GraphQlDataFetcher`, can you try doing this instead?

```
<input type="file" onChange={ event => this.uploadFile(event, refetch) } />
```

Answer (score 1):

0xc14m1z's answer is correct.

Here is a 'cleaner' syntax to solve your problem by preconfiguring your function :

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.uploadFile(refetch)} />
```

And your function :

```
uploadFile = async refetch => event => {
```